# Rails Back button doesn't direct to last page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I'm creating a sample project and I've found that the back button doesn't take me to the last screen in one case. It seemingly randomly either takes me to a blank page with no url or another index page. Here's some context.

In my PostsController index.html.erb file I have a text_field_tag. When a string is inputted into this field I have some js that detects that and calls a post method in the controller called check_uri. Here's the js

```
 $ ->
   $(document).on 'input', '#post-model-url-field', ->
     $.post '/posts/check_uri', { post_url: $(this).val()}
```

This correctly calls the check_uri action in the PostsController and in that method I check the uri's form and if it matches I use:

```
redirect_to new_post_path
```

Which directs the browser to 'posts/new'

This all seems to be working correctly however when I press the back button from new.html it randomly takes me to either a blank screen with no url or some other page on the site, not posts/index which is where I was at. Is there something I can do about this or another way to approach this problem that would allow the back button to work?

Comment: How are you redirecting the user? Sending a request with ajax should not redirect the browser.

Comment: I'm calling redirect_to new_post_path in check_uri action

Comment: You should never redirect a user in an ajax request.